# Is there a way to run a unit test inside a different unit test?

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am writing some python x selenium unit tests for the login functionality of a website. I have already written a unit test for a valid login, but I want to write one for the "Remember Me" functionality. I could easily just copy/paste the login unit test code into the new one, but that would make a VERY long block of code. I was wondering if there was any way to utilize another unit test's code for a separate unit test in order to save some room.

Comment: Can you add your test to the question? You could create a function that both tests call or you could parametrize the test

Answer (score 0):

It's not about utilization unit tests.
You should write your methods / classes in a way they can be utilized easily.
So that your login method will call similar methods that "remember me" method uses but with appropriate changes according to scenario flow differences.

Comment: Generally I'd agree, but the question is about a Selenium test, i.e.,it runs in the browser. Are you suggesting to split the test case in reusable methods?

Comment: First, I guess these are different test cases. Second, each test can contain several methods calls, like any other method containing of several code lines / method calls inside it

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the test case in multiple methods. For example, you could have `openLoginPage` and `loginAs(String user, String password, boolean rememberMe)` and then use these methods in the individual tests.

If you keep taking this further, you'll get to [Page Objects](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/page_object_models/), where you hide all the details of a page (like field and button IDs) in the page object, and the test case uses high-level method calls on those page objects. Each test that needs to log in can reuse the `LoginPage` object.